# Proper pattern for funneling processing of multiple streams into a single stream

Tags: java, spring-cloud-dataflow

Right now I have one stream application in SCDF that is pulling data from multiple tables in a database and replicating it to another database. Currently, our goal is to reduce the amount of work that a given stream is doing, so we want to split the stream out into multiple streams and continue replicating the data into the second database.

Are there any recommended design patterns for funneling the processing of these various streams into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this requirement correctly, you'd want to split the ingest piece by DB/Table per App and then merge them all into a single "payload type" for downstream processing.

If you really do want to split the ingest by DB/Table, you can, but you may want to consider the pros/cons, though. One obvious benefit is granularity and that you can independently update the App in isolation, and maybe also reusability. Of course, it brings other challenges. Maintenance, fixes, and releases for individual apps to name a few.

That said, you can fan-in data to a single consumer. Here's an example:

> foo1 = jdbc | transform | hdfs
>
> foo2 = jdbc > :foo1.jdbc
>
> foo3 = jdbc > :foo1.jdbc
>
> foo4 = jdbc > :foo1.jdbc

Here, `foo1` is the primary pipeline reading data from a particular DB/Table combination. Likewise, `foo2`, `foo3`, and `foo4` could read from other DB/Table combinations. However, these 3 streams are writing the consumed data to a named-destination, which in this case happens to be `foo1.jdbc` (aka: topic name). This destination is automatically created by SCDF when deploying the `foo1` pipeline; specifically to connect "jdbc" and "transform" Apps with the `foo1.jdbc` topic.

In summary, we are routing the different table data to land in the same destination, so the downstream App, in this case, the `transform` processor gets the data from different tables.

If the correlation of data is important, you can partition the data at the producer by a unique key (e.g., customer-id = 1001) at each `jdbc` source, so context-specific information land at the same `transform` processor instance *(assuming you've "n" number of processor instances for scaled-out processing)*.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I found some information regarding Named Destinations in SCDF that was very useful here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-dsl-named-destinations

Comment: Nice! Please be sure to use the latest release, though. v1.2.3 is very old. The current GA release is at v1.6 - you can follow the [platform table](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#platform-implementations) in the project site for the release bits and the corresponding platform-specific docs.